# How to run code after rspec generates report?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to post-process the json report generated by `rspec --format json --out output.json` and publish test result metrics to a service.

Is there an rspec hook (or any equivalent way) that would run after the file is generated? The pytest equivalent hook is implementing the `def session_finish` method and I'm looking to accomplish something similar with rspec.

The main goal is to keep this post-processing within the `rspec` command, without having to run another side-script dedicated to post processing the output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

RSpec has a number of [after hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), but in all likelihood you want the `after(:suite)` block for your use case. If you'd prefer to do something at the end of all suites instead, you might try registering your own action using [Kernel#at_exit](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) instead.